# Bibliography won't appear using \usepackage{tocbibbind}

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, tocbibind

Hi all I have a a preamble as follows but cannot seem to get the bibliography to appear in the table of contents:

```
%Loading in the packages
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

then in the main body do the following roughly:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist, style=custom_acronyms]

\chapter{test}
\input{chapters/test}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I successfully have items appearing in the bibliography and the bibliography displays without an issue but it doesn't appear in the table of contents although the list of figures and the glossary appear no issue! having so many issues with Latex sadly...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use the facilities of `biblatex` for making the bibliography to go into the table of contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues (glossaries, empty title etc), but I focused on the ToC entry of the bibliography.

`\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]` will add this automatically, there is no need for `tocbibind` for this special usage.

(I replaced `references.bib` with the system `biblio.bib`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm ,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

%\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist, style=custom_acronyms]

%\chapter{test}
%\input{chapters/test}

\cite{Lam94}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thankyou very much, very much appreciated! will accept ASAP

Comment: finnaly, my quest has come to an end! All those solutions with `\addcontentsline` and `\usepackage{tocbibind}` did not seem to work, but this little option did it! Thank you sooo much!